# Multiple background colors in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, textmate

I'm trying to get my emacs color scheme set up like I have it in Textmate. Currently, variables, methods, and comments have a different background color than the main body. See the following link for an example.

Is this possible in emacs?

[image]

Comment: My eyes! The goggles do nothing!

Comment: haha. well i like it.

Comment: I kind of like the "angry fruit salad" look. I started out programming on a green screen WYSE 60, so its not a "kids these days" thing.

Comment: Will you share the source of your hand-baked color theme?

Comment: i WISH i were creative enough to hand-bake it. it's a (very) modified version of monokai called monokai for textmaters CUSTOM by James Hicks. you can check it out here: http://pastie.org/205164

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.  The command you are looking for is `M-x customize-face`.  Each different *thing* (variable, method, etc) has a face associated with it.  For instance `font-lock-comment-face`.

If you put the point on a character, at type `M-x list-text-properties-at` it will tell you what face is being used to display that character.

If you type `M-x list-faces-display`, it will show you all of the faces.

Comment: thanks. this helps a lot! "M-x list-properties-at" doesn't work for me, but it's good to know that it can be done.

Comment: My mistake.  That should be M-x list-text-properties-at